# Несовместимость трансляторов VS2017 и GCC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день.

Пишу простой код:

```
template<float(*math_fun)(float)> float run_math_fun(float arg) {
float ret = (*math_fun)(arg);
return ret;
}

float ddd() {
float a = 10.0;
return run_math_fun<&fabs>(a);
}
```

Транслятор VS2017 нормально транслирует этот код.

Транслятор GCC (из состава wxDev-C++) транслировать этот код отказывается и выдает следующую диагностику:

```
In function 'float ob_charspace::ddd()'::  
no matching function for call to 'run_math_fun(float&)' 
candidate is:
template<float (* math_fun)(float)> float ob_charspace::run_math_fun(float)
[Build Error]  [obj/ob7.o] Error 1
```

При этом саму функцию fabs транслятор GCC видит, понимает и, если вызвать fabs 
 явно, то трансляция проходит нормально.

Вопрос:

1. Что не нравится транслятору GCC в этом коде?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fabs` без namespace'а — это Си'шный вариант. В C++ надо сделать одно из трёх:

```
// 1; будет ли работать зависит от деталей реализации libm
#include <math.h>

// 2
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// 3
#include <cmath>
// ... 
return run_math_fun<&std::fabs>(a);
```

Последнее ИМХО предпочтительнее.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло включение cmath вместо math.h. А using namespace std; там и раньше было. Странно, что VS2017 все понимал, а GCC отказывался.

Comment: гм... по мне с точностью до наоборот... ну да ладно... похоже libm в комплекте с mingw несколько отличается от glibc'шной.

Comment: Когда там было math.h, саму fabs можно было вызвать без всякого префикса std::fabs, и транслятор GCC это понимал. Но как аргумент шаблона почему-то отказывался понимать.

Comment: мм... ясно... просто у себя на `{x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,i686-w64-mingw32}-g++-6.4.0` я воспроизвести это не смог...

Comment: В  wxDev-C++ сам транслятор GCC древний как фекалии  мамонта. Версии 3.х.х не помню точно какой. Да и вообще этот проект (wxDev-C++) похоже умер. Не обновляется с 2012 года. Пользуюсь им только чтобы проверить, что код транслируется под GCC. И только потому, что там есть IDE и не надо разбираться с ключами командной строки GCC.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Зачем вам эти мамонты? Пользуйтесь [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) и актуальной версией [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/).

Answer (score 1):

Согласно тому, что вы написали в комментариях, ради доступа к `fabs` вы включаете `<math.h>`. Однако простой эксперимент показывает, что при включении только `<math.h>` ваш код не компилируется ни в VS2017, ни в GCC, по одной и той же причине - не существует функции `fabs`, которая принимала бы аргумент типа `float` и возвращала бы результат типа `float`. Такой код и не должен компилироваться. Так что никакой несовместимости между компиляторами тут нет.

Для компилируемости вашего кода нужно включение `<cmath>`. Очевидно, что у вас в случае с VS2017 этот заголовочный файл оказался включенным тоже: он оказался неявно/случайно включенным через посредство каких-то других заголовочных файлов стандартной библиотеки С++. Это случайное включение `<cmath>` и приводило к компилируемости кода. В GCC это случайное включение не имеет места, вследствие чего в GCC код не компилируется.

---

Также следует заметить, что компоненты стандартной библиотеки в заголовочном файле `<cmath>` должны быть объявлены в пространстве имен `std`. Однако не оговаривается, каким образом это достигается: либо прямым объявлением этих имен в `std`, либо объявлением этих имен в глобальном пространстве имен и последующим переобъявлением их в `std` при помощи using-объявлений.

Компоненты стандартной библиотеки в заголовочном файле `<math.h>` должно быть объявлены в глобальном пространстве имен. Но совершенно симметричным образом этот заголовочный файл может внутреннее сначала объявлять эти имена в пространстве имен `std`, а затем переобъявлять их в глобальном пространстве имен при помощи using-объявлений.

Это значит, что доступность этих имен в "альтернативном" пространстве имен может варьироваться от реализации к реализации. Включая `<cmath>` вы гарантированно получите имена в в пространстве имен `std`, и при этом можете получить (а можете и не получить) эти имена в глобальном пространстве имен. С `<math.h>` ситуация обратная.

То есть подобный эффект может возникать и по таким причинам. Но эксперимент показывает, что в данном случае дело просто в неявном включении `<cmath>`.

Comment: [Во-первых, приведенный вам код не компилируется ни MSVC, ни GCC.] Конечно это не полный пример. Для начала тут нет main. Идея в том, что один и тот же кусок кода компилировался в VS2017 и не компилировался в GCC. Все остальное было одинаковым, включая заголовочные файлы и директивы using.

Comment: [Поэтому на что вы надеялись, включая (согласно комментариям) <math.h> и пытаясь затем передавать fabs как float (*)(float) - не ясно.] Мне очень неловко, но для транслятора VS2017 fabs с аргументом double прекрасно странслировалась как аргумент шаблона, хотя в шаблоне и стоял указатель на функцию с аргументом float. А после всех манипуляций он странслировался и на GCC. Скорее всего это потому, что при инстанцировании шаблона доступные преобразования типа учитываются.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: "Скорее всего это потому, что при инстанцировании шаблона доступные преобразования типа учитываются. " - нет, не учитываются. Во-первых, простой эксперимент с VS2017 показывает, что VS2017 не определяет С++ версии `fabs` в `<math.h>`. В чистом виде ваш код НЕ компилируется в VS2017 с `<math.h>` (см. http://rextester.com/OQXR42161). То есть если это у вас компилировалось в VS2017 - то только потому, что какой-то *другой* заголовок неявно/случайно включил `<cmath>`. В GCC этого неявного включения не оказалось и код перестал компилироваться. Вот и все объяснение.

Comment: Во-вторых, вы ведь, наверное, не ожидали заранее, что `<math.h>` будет вдруг ни с того ни с сего определять С++ версию `fabs`, правда? Поэтому вопрос про "на что вы надеялись" все равно актуален.

Comment: [какой-то другой заголовок неявно/случайно включил <cmath>] Даже если это и так. Так как все хедеры для варианта VS2017 и для варианта GCC были одинаковыми, то это означает в том числе несовместимость VS2017 и GCC по составу включаемых хедерами функций.