# C++, C и функция abs

Tags: c++, c

Есть, значит, код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << abs(4.1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(Специально показал инклюды, тут нет `cmath`).

Под рукой был лишь Windows.

Собираем с компилятором от Microsoft. Вывод:

```
4.1
```

Собираем с g++ (MinGW). Вывод:

```
4
```

Окей, ничего не понятно.

Подключим-ка `<cmath>`. Ничего не меняется...

Подключаем `<math.h>`. Теперь все в порядке на обоих компиляторах.

Хорошо. Будем думать, что по-дефолту каким-то боком используется `c`-шная `abs`, оперирующая интами (для g++). Переписываем код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << fabs(4.1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод `cl`:

```
4.1
```

Вывод g++:

```
А фиг вам, <cmath> подключить не хотите-ли?
```

Вывод g++ (после подключения `<cmath>`):

```
4.1
```

Ура!

Так вот, скажите:

Почему я могу использовать `abs`, ничего для этого не подключая - мне понятно. У меня включен `<iostream>`, а значит - и `<stdlib.h>`. Но из-за чего такие различия для разных компиляторов? Такое чувство, что компилятор от майкрософт где-то подключает `<math.h>`...

Да, кстати. Вопрос именно про использование `c`-функций `abs`. С `std::abs` я проблем не замечал.

Comment: подключая `<cmath>` вы делаете что-то типа `namespace std{ #include <math.h>}`, вы знаете, да ? Это я вот про это:
`Подключим-ка <cmath>. Ничего не меняется... Подключаем <math.h>. Теперь все в порядке на обоих компиляторах.`

Comment: То есть подключая math.h (или cmath) вы получили и abs(int) и abs(double), а не подключая вы получаете только abs(int) - из stdlib, и 4.1 приводится к int (на g++). А вот под виндой видимо был доступен ещё abs(double), как вы  и предположили

Comment: @vegorov просто меня расстраивает такая путаница. Я на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795092/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-10-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) отвечал, и некрасиво вышло, ибо на разных компиляторах разный результат вышел)

Comment: Теперь [попробуйте clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zl0eCivUlwiiCIrM)

Comment: По поводу пространств имен подробно расписано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790151/182825, а дальше просто срабатывает неявное включение чего-то через `<iostream>`.

Comment: @VTT да, довольно забавно. По крайней мере, еще один аргумент в копилку `std::abs` перед `abs` + `using...`...

Comment: Ваш код формально некорректен. Не существует требований унификации поведения разных компиляторов для некорректного кода. Вопрос "Но из-за чего такие различия для разных компиляторов?" не имеет смысла.

Comment: @AnT это, в принципе, понятно, мне больше была интересна логика, которой руководствовались эти компиляторы при включении/не включении определенных заголовков. Но, как я теперь понял, логики особой тут искать и не нужно, лучше просто использовать стандартные функции.

Comment: @selya: Это в С с неявным включением заголовков очень строго. В С++ - полный разброд и шатание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код нерабочий в обоих случаях, так как в нем (1) идут попытки использовать эффекты от непрямого включения заголовочных файлов (2) идут попытки использовать нестандартные функции. Эффекты могут рандомно различаться как у разных компиляторов, так и у одного компилятора с разными настройками. Вот например перегрузка `::std::abs(double` начиная с C++17 есть в заголовочном файле `<cstdlib>`, но перегрузки `::abs(double` при этом там может и не быть.